# Running an angular 2 application built locally on Chrome using angular-cli without a node server

Tags: javascript, angular, webpack, ember-cli, angular-cli

I will make my **Angular 2** question very precise.

**1. I am using:**

Angular 2,
   angular-cli: 1.0.0-beta.15, ( webpack building )
   node: 6.4.0, 
   os: linux x64

**2. What I want to achieve:**

I want to build my project in a way that after the build **( ng build project-name )** I get static files of my Angular 2 application, which I can run directly from chrome without using **ng serve** or the node server. **I just want to double click index.html and run the app locally.**

**3. Meanwhile, what I get in the chrome browser console output when I double click the generated index.html is:**

> file:///inline.js Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
>       file:///styles.b52d2076048963e7cbfd.bundle.js Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
>       file:///main.c45bb457f14bdc0f5b96.bundle.js Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
>       file:///favicon.ico Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND

4. As I understand this is related to paths. The built and bundled application cannot find the right paths. So my question is **where** and **how** I should change **the paths** in my app or in any **build configuration files** in order for my app to work like I would like it to work in the way I have described in **point number 2**
5. Thank you in advance for a direct and full answer on that topic, because other topics are not explaining the full scope on that subject.

Comment: I think the problem is using the `file://` URL. I'm pretty sure this disables some JS features (like XHR) because of security concerns. What's wrong with using a server?

Comment: I can't run in it on a server. I need static files that is why. I am not gonna run the application on a PC or MAC. I need to run it using only a browser like Chrome, without any server.

Answer (score 32):

**First Step:**

Run the command

```
ng build
```

or

```
ng build -prod (then it will compact all files for production version)
```

**Second Step:**

Change in index.html

```
<base href="/"> to <base href="./">
```

**Third Step:**

Put all files into server(may be htdocs in localhost or any server)

Hopefully it will work.

Comment: second step does the magic. but why? why dot needs to be added manually

Comment: @Khaleel because to make sure your file paths are relative to the current directory rather than relative to the root directory we have to add `.`

Comment: @Khaleel You can add the dot to your main index.html file and it will carry over to the production version so you don't have to add it manually each time.

Answer (score 29):

**Solution without server**:

**First Step**:

Change in `index.html`:

remove `<base href="/">`

**Second Step:**

Change in `app.module.ts`:

```
import { CommonModule, APP_BASE_HREF, LocationStrategy, HashLocationStrategy} from '@angular/common';

@NgModule({
   providers: [
       { provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: '/' },
       { provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: HashLocationStrategy }
   ]
})
```

**Third Step:**

Run the command

```
ng build
```

or

```
ng build -prod
```

Doubleclick `dist/index.html` to see the result.

Comment: This was the only one that worked for me. If the base tag was left in the index.html (even if it were set to ./ or . or whatever) caused the page to try to attempt to push state, which was not supported on file///

Comment: This worked for me, thanks! @Bartb, would you mind accepting this as the answer?

Comment: It really works, but the problem is.
Application runs at : 'file:///C:/Users/000000/Desktop/assignment1/index.html#/login'
but looking for json files at: 
'file:///C:/Users/assets/json/userStory.json'

where as it should have been 
'file:///C:/Users/000000/Desktop/assignment1/assets/json/userStory.json' .
Please help.

Comment: This worked for me. However, I created a font-family in my app using the font files which I load from the assets folder. It worked correctly with the ng serve command but doesn't work this way. Why ?

Answer (score 11):

If you're using Angular-Cli you don't need to amend index.html after building the project.
As per Angular-CLi github document https://github.com/angular/angular-cli#base-tag-handling-in-indexhtml
 you can simply modify  argument while you're building the project:

```
    Example: ng build --prod --base-href .
```

The actual Usage is:

```
ng build --base-href <base>
```

you can simply introduce a specific url instead of base. In this example we use . (dot) as an argument

Comment: once i set base set manually i works, but from command line not working , don't know why, have you tested it ?

Comment: Unknown option: '--bh'

Comment: ```ng build --base-href ./ ```

Answer (score 11):

A simple solution: Change your base href when you build.

```
ng build --prod --base-href .
```

Now you can double click the `index.html` file and it will work.

Here is an example of this working: https://mattspaulding.github.io/angular-material-starter/

Comment: Unknown option: '--bh'

Comment: ```ng build --base-href ./ ```

Comment: Did you put a built app online?
Could you pls have a look at my question?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73501892/how-to-serve-a-built-angular-app-that-is-running-in-my-browser

Answer (score 7):

You must serve the `/dist` folder using an HTTP server. You can't get around this because loading files locally doesn't allow code execution for security reasons.

The server doesn't have to be something heavy like Express or even a highly featured minimalist one like HapiJS. The built in Node http-server will do just fine. If you've already got Apache, nginx, or IIS set up you can also use them to serve your app.

EDIT: I did some moral searching and decided to offer up a solution I personally wouldn't use, but may be a good fit for you: [Web Server for Chrome Extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/web-server-for-chrome/ofhbbkphhbklhfoeikjpcbhemlocgigb?hl=en)

Comment: Thank you very much :) But I need this bundle to work on a mobile device which uses webkit but not Android or iOS but Tizen. Inside there is webkit, so I can't rely direclty on Google Chrome. But thank you for your research.

Comment: Tizen? That's some important info that belongs in your post!

Comment: Also, your best option is to just implement a NodeJS HTTP server that serves your `/dist`. It's less than 50 lines max, and the CLI already has dependencies on it.

Comment: Yes. Tizen is running on webkit. Since a lot of people don't know what Tizen is and I know Tizen very good, then I asked about webkit. Answer for webkit would solve the problem on Tizen. But thank you for your reply :).

Comment: +1 for the only answer which explains why loading index.html from /dist directory does not work. However, still to find more details on why angular produced static html with referenced javascript files are a security threat. And why that works when I just write a simple html with javascript files in the same folder.

Comment: The threat is cross site scripting and the reason things don't work is part of Cross Origin Request Sharing. Your requests must originate from the same location and/or all pre-flight checks must be responded to properly. When you don't have a server to respond to your `OPTIONS` pre-flight the browser goes "NOPE" and rejects responses because they don't match the allowed headers, methods, or some other tiny little bit of the CORS puzzle.

Answer (score 3):

All you need is to build your app using this one line of code:

```
ng build --prod --base-href ./
```

Answer (score 1):

I recommend use Expressjs, why servers how xampp, laragon, etc... the routes not work well, I did it like that:  I created new folder with name server, inside copied an file **index.js**, the route would be "src/assets/server/index.js" ,

Index.js content

```js
var express = require('express'),
    path = require('path'),
    fs = require('fs');

var app = express();
var staticRoot = __dirname + '/../../';

app.set('port', (process.env.PORT || 80));

app.use(express.static(staticRoot));

app.use(function(req, res, next){
    var accept = req.accepts('html', 'json', 'xml');
    if(accept !== 'html'){
        return next();
    }
    var ext = path.extname(req.path);
    if (ext !== ''){
        return next();
    }
    fs.createReadStream(staticRoot + 'index.html').pipe(res);

});
app.listen(app.get('port'), function() {
    console.log('app running on port', app.get('port'));
});
```

In package.json, inside the root of project

```js
{
    "dependencies": {
        "express": "4.13.4"
    }
}
```

later, run in console command **ng build prod** and run

> node dist/assets/server/

this command execute an express server, indicating the direction of file config our server, on this occasion, the file **index.js preconfigured**

p.s: sorry for my bad english, I am learning

Answer (score 1):

Removing `<base href="/">` from `index.html` worked for me.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/20109779)

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre This actually solve the problem for me

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve something like this using nw.js for example (or electron). I created an app myself that uses angular 2 locally with nw.js and it works like a charm ;)

nwjs.io

Comment: No, at least at the moment not. But you didn't mention that you needed mobile support.

Comment: Nevertheless I will try to run it on Tizen. It is the same like running on webkit. If it runs on webkit and does need any server then it must run on Tizen. Thank you for your answer :).

Answer (score 0):

use ng serve --open to build the application and start a web server