# How do I build my angular 8 app so that it works when opening index.html in browser?

Tags: angular, angular-cli, github-pages

I just finished working on an angular 8 app and I am trying to host it on github pages. My problem is that when I try to build the app via `ng build --prod` and open the index.html of the dist folder in my browser. It just reads the content of that file and throws a bunch of :

> Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FAILED
>
> Access to script at 'file:///D:/weather/Wapp/dist/Wapp/runtime-es2015.edb2fcf2778e7bf1d426.js' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https.

I tried changing the href in the html manually and via commands and attempted multiple answers of this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39771458/running-an-angular-2-application-built-locally-on-chrome-using-angular-cli-witho) but nothing worked.I also want to mention that the built website works fine in a localserver with server-lite.

this is the structure of the dist folder :

```
D:.
└───Wapp
    │   3rdpartylicenses.txt
    │   favicon.ico
    │   index.html
    │   main-es2015.3597f5e65f4450662a55.js
    │   main-es5.3597f5e65f4450662a55.js
    │   polyfills-es2015.2987770fde9daa1d8a2e.js
    │   polyfills-es5.6696c533341b95a3d617.js
    │   runtime-es2015.edb2fcf2778e7bf1d426.js
    │   runtime-es5.edb2fcf2778e7bf1d426.js
    │   styles.44d5eaa2a1e46e8873ec.css
    │
    └───assets
            rain.svg
            wi-sandstorm.svg
```

any help will be welcome, thank you.

Comment: that's because you are accessing a file via `file://` protocol. You'd better simply run you angular app using `ng serve`.

Answer (score 0):

Basically Angular 2+ is not designed to work off of the file system without a web server.
If you really need to serve an angular 2+ app from the file system I would consider electron as a better solution. Otherwise, you can use `lite-server` a very lightweight development web server.

OR the normal way

```
ng serve
```

**Note** : However, there is a small hack which will work for most case (not recommended):

Solution without a server:

**First Step:**

Change in `index.html`:

remove `<base href="/">`

**Second Step:**

Change in `app.module.ts`:

```js
import { CommonModule, APP_BASE_HREF, LocationStrategy, HashLocationStrategy} from '@angular/common';

@NgModule({
   providers: [
       { provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: '/' },
       { provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: HashLocationStrategy }
   ]
})
```

**Third Step:**

Run the command

```
ng build
```

or

```
ng build -prod
```

Doubleclick `dist/index.html` to see the result.