# How to serve a built Angular app that is running in my browser?

Tags: angular

I have a an application that converted an IBM Notes db in to a angular app.
I can access the Notes files trough the index.html by simply opening it in my browser.
Once it works in my browser, I would like to host it in a server.
I have created a server and I have exposed the index.html but all I see is a blank page.
Below is the index file. I can inspect it and see the html.
Maybe , when I run it in a server, it the index is not calling the js files?
What should I do in order to serve the index and see everything just the way I see when I
simply open it in my browser?

[image]

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Teamstudio Export</title>
  <!--<base href="/">-->

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css"></head>

<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
  <script src="runtime.js" defer></script>
  <script src="polyfills-es5.js" nomodule defer></script>
  <script src="polyfills.js" defer></script>
  <script src="main.js" defer></script>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

One thing I notice is that you have commented out the `<base href="/">` tag, you will more than likely need this.  And often times I have personally had to make the tag look like this `<base href="./">` which is simply just adding a period in front of the slash. This just tells the server where the file is that you would like to have shown to begin with.

Comment: I was able to run it using the node http-server. So it run in my localhost. No need to uncomment the "<base href="/">". Now, how do I replicate it in my server.

Comment: A few of the angular apps I have built all from the start use that `<base href="./">` to handle their routing when deployed to a local server even.  I am unsure how you are getting it to work without it unless you are doing a couple extra steps to set up the way your app is hosted on a server.  Here is a link you could take a peek at and see if some of the information can help you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51182322/whats-the-difference-between-base-href-and-deploy-url-parameters-of-angular

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution and it is very simple.
I have just created a node server that serves the folder where all those files are.
I have added all the files in the public folder and I serve it as static.
I have deplyed it in my server and it is working like a charm
Se code example below

```
const express = require('express')
const app =express()

app.use(express.static('public')) //all files inside the public folder

app.listen(5000,()=>{
    console.log('✅ Server running on  http://127.0.0.1:5000/')
})
```